# About the implicit funtion in a holomorphic situation.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory

Let $f(x,y)$ be a polonomial with integral coefficients which has a zero $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that the partial derivative respect to $y$ at this point is nonzero. Then by the implicit function theorem we have a neighborhood $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ and a differenciable in $U$ function $y(x)$ such that

$f(x,y(x))=0.$

My question is the following:

Can I find a neighborhood $V\subset \mathbb{C}$ and a holomorphic function $Y(x)$ in $V$ such that

$f(x,Y(x))=0?$

Particularly is there a holomorphic implicit function theorem?

Thanks

Comment: Yes and yes. I'm too lazy to go into details now, but if you look closely at the proof of the implicit function theorem, you will see it works for holomorphic functions.

Comment: Thanks, do you know any reference? it would be very helpful

Comment: It's Theorem 2.4 in Range, Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables, for example. But it should appear in most introductory texts on several complex variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first forget the complex structure, then this is a standard situation for the implicit function theorem with $F:\Bbb R^4\to \Bbb R^2$. The corollary of the theorem tells you that if $F(x,y)$ is $k$ times continuously differentiable, then so is $Y(x)$.

Here you only need the first derivative. Now reinserting back the complex structure, one finds that the derivative of $Y(x)$ inherits the complex structure from $F$ and its partial derivatives, so that $Y(x)$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann partial differential equations and is thus holomorph.